How to break an amount to a defined multiple, with a defined start and end date, into totals for a week
Sample Data
Start with:
Table 1                         Names
Type    Start       End         XXX     XYZ
A       2024-10-31  2024-11-13  48.25   47
B       2024-11-05  2024-11-14  0.75    80.5
C       2024-10-31  2024-10-31          5

Finish with:
Table 2         
Type    Name    2024-10-28  2024-11-04  2024-11-11
A       XXX     9.75        23.75       14.75
A       XYZ     9.5         23.25       14.25
B       XXX     0           0.25        0.5
B       XYZ     0           40.25       40.25
C       XYZ     5           0           0

Goal:
So this is like an unpivot if I have the term correct.  I am basically trying to break apart a qty by a given multiple. I then spread that base multiple across all days, and add the left over on the end and start days working inward until there is not left over.  Then just to simplify things, sum the results by week starting on Monday.
Note:   The QTY will always be an integer when divided by the designated multiple value.
        Table 1 is in another workbook and is just a bunch of cells in a worksheet.
        Table 2 is in the codes workbook and is a named table.  I have it defined as a listobject.
        Holidays are currently being ignored. (ie note a current factor)

What I have figured out.

Take the count and divide it by the number of weekdays
Round the result down by the multiple amount
Determine the left over time
Find the number of days with extra days
Split the extra time days equally between start and end with end getting extra day when extra day count is odd.
Somehow apply the base amount to all days
Somehow apply the multiple amount to the start extra days
Somehow apply the multiple amount to the end extra days
somehow sum the hours by the appropriate week
paste the hours into the results table at the appropriate intersection of date and "A-XXX" combo

My thought process on a spreadsheet

I am trying to wrap my head through this.  I think I have the process thought out.  I am trying to figure out how to do this in VBA.  I am not the strongest with Arrays, but something tells me that an array would be the best approach for this.
code
This is my current code, and its completely a work in progress, and something in my the back of my head says it may need to be completely revamped in that end section (after the 888 For loop).
Private Sub LoadPPT_Click()

Dim frm As PPT_Picker_Form
Dim wbPPT As Workbook
Dim wsPPT As Worksheet
Dim rngTopLeft As Range, rngBotRight As Range, rngPPTTable As Range
Dim lngLastUsedRow As Long
Dim lngLastCol As Long
Dim rngTargetCell As Range
Dim rngNameRow As Range
Dim rngNameCellFirst As Range, rngNameCellLast As Range
Dim lngTimeStart As Long
Dim rngStartDateCol As Range
Dim rngEndDateCol As Range
Dim rngHours As Range
Dim InputTable As ListObject
Dim lngInsertRow As Long
Dim lngPPTRowCounter As Long
Dim lngPPTColCounter As Long
Dim dStartDate As Date
Dim dEndDate As Date
Dim lngWeeks As Long
Dim dTaskSM As Date
Dim dTaskEM As Date
Dim lngTaskDays As Long
Dim dbTaskHoursPerDay As Double
Dim dbTaskDayUnits As Double
Dim dbTaskExtraUnitDays As Long
Dim lngDayCoutner As Long
Dim TestDate As Date
Dim dbWeek1Hours As Double
Dim dbWeeknHours As Double
Dim dbWeekLhours As Bouble



'Public strPPTFilepath As String
'Public strProjectNumber As String
    Set InputTable = Me.ListObjects("Forecast_Table")
    
    Set frm = UserForms.Add(PPT_Picker_Form.Name)
    frm.ListData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Project Numbers").ListObjects("Project_Number_List").DataBodyRange
    
    frm.show
        
    If bCancelled Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'Define PPT Table
        
    Set wbPPT = Workbooks.Open(strPPTFilepath)
    Set wsPPT = wbPPT.Worksheets("Fee Estimate")
    
    'Find top left corner
    With wsPPT.Cells
        Set rngTopLeft = .Find("WBS Code", LookIn:=xlFormulas)
        
        If rngTopLeft Is Nothing Then
            'nothing found
            'add a manual cell picker routine
        End If
        
        Set rngTopLeft = rngTopLeft.Offset(2, 0)
    End With
    
    'Find last row
    lngLastUsedRow = wsPPT.Cells(wsPPT.Rows.count, rngTopLeft.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    
    'find Right edge
    With wsPPT.Cells
        Set rngTargetCell = .Find("Name", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        'Assume first name is to the right of the cell containing "Name"
        Set rngNameCellFirst = rngTargetCell.Offset(0, 1)
                
        If rngTargetCell Is Nothing Then
            'nothing found
            'add a manual cell picker routine
        End If
        
        Do While rngTargetCell <> ""
            Set rngTargetCell = rngTargetCell.Cells.Offset(0, 1)
            lngLastCol = rngTargetCell.Column
        Loop
            
        Set rngNameCellLast = rngTargetCell.Cells.Offset(0, -1)
        lngLastCol = lngLastCol - 1
            
        Set rngTargetCell = .Find("Start Date", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        Set rngStartDateCol = wsPPT.Range(rngTargetCell.Offset(2, 0), wsPPT.Cells(lngLastUsedRow, rngTargetCell.Column))
        
        Set rngTargetCell = .Find("End Date", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        Set rngEndDateCol = wsPPT.Range(rngTargetCell.Offset(2, 0), wsPPT.Cells(lngLastUsedRow, rngTargetCell.Column))
        
        Set rngTargetCell = .Find("Units", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        Set rngHours = wsPPT.Range(rngTargetCell.Offset(2, 0), wsPPT.Cells(lngLastUsedRow, rngNameCellLast.Column))
        
    End With
    
    'Define PPT table
    Set rngPPTTable = wsPPT.Range(rngTopLeft, wsPPT.Cells(lngLastUsedRow, lngLastCol))
    Set rngNameRow = wsPPT.Range(rngNameCellFirst, rngNameCellLast)
    
    InsertRow = TableLastUsedRow
    
   ' strProjectNumber
    If InputTable.ListRows(InputTable.ListRows.count).Range.Row = InsertRow Then
        InputTable.ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True
        InsertRow = InsertRow + 1
    End If
    
    
        
        For lngPPTRowCounter = 1 To 888
            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rngPPTTable.Row(lngPPTRowCounter)) <> 0 Then
                InputTable.ListColumns("Project No").ListRow(InsertRow) = strProjectNumber
                InputTable.ListColumns("Task No").ListRow(InsertRow) = rngPPTTable.Cells(PPTRowCounter, 2) & " - " & rngPPTTable.Cells(PPTRowCounter, 3)
                InputTable.ListColumns("Staff").ListRow(InsertRow) = rngNameRow(PPTColCounter)
                'Insert Funtcion to fill in Office Based on Name
                dStartDate = rngStartDate(rngPPTRowCounter)
                dEndDate = rngEndDate(rngPPTRowCounter)
                dTaskSM = Monday_Date(dStartDate)
                dTaskEM = Monday_Date(dEndDate)
                lngTaskDays = WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays(dStartDate, dEndDate)
                
                For lngPPTColCounter = 1 To 999
                    If rngHours(lngPPTRowCounter, lngPPTColCounter) > 0 Then
                        dbTaskHoursPerDay = WorksheetFunction.RoundDown((rngHours(lngPPTRowCounter, lngPPTColCounter) / lngTaskDays) / 0.25, 0) * 0.25
                        If dbTaskHoursPerDay = 0 Then
                            'Outside in fill to 0 routine
                        Else
                        dbTaskDayUnits = rngHours(lngPPTRowCounter, lngPPTColCounter) / dbTaskHoursPerDay
                        dbTaskExtraUnitDays = dbTaskDayUnits Mod lngTaskDays
                        
                        TestDate = dStartDate
                        
                        For lngDayCounter = 1 To (dEndate - dStartDate)
                            If Weekday(TestDate) > 1 And Weekday(TestDate) < 7 Then
                                If TestDate < dTaskSM + 5 Then
                                    Week1hours= Week1Hours+
                                ElseIf TestDate < dTaskEM - 2 Then
                                
                                Else
                                
                            End If
                        
                        
                        
                        Week1EndDate
                        Week2ndLastEndDate
                         
                        
                    
                    End If
            End If
        
        
        Next lngPPTRowCounter
    Next lngPPTColCounter
    
End Sub

Question
How can I improve my current approach to essentially get from Table 1 to Table 2?

Quite an endeavor. It interests me. I wanna help but I don't think I can find XYC in your data. Did you make a mistake with XYC being XYZ. I think I got what you wanna do. I haven't read the VBA code thoroughly yet. But from the cursory look, I think you should get the Table 2 right first before thinking about userform at the same time. I mean, if and when we got the Table 2 right, we can work on userform. Maybe I am wrong but like I said, I haven't gone deep with code as of now. I also think that your explanation can improve a bit so that people can help you better. Also upped from -2 to -1.

You are absolutely correct.  XYC was a typo.  I had C on my mind as I was adding a special case C at the time.  XYC is actually XYZ and I have adjusted the sample data to reflect this.

The user form in my code is for the user to enter a project number and select the import file.  Its working so a non issue for breaking down the data into a different format.

Removed XYC references in examples data and in my thought process sheet.  Also added a column and some line work in the thought process sheet to hopefully make it easier to follow.

I’m not sure I fully understand the logic of your question, but I believe it aims to distribute the workload (or other things) across each week. I’ve developed a different approach—please note the [Amt] and [Week] in the output, as they differ slightly from your results. If you find my output accurate, it can easily be converted into a 2D table format as you expected.
Sub demo2()
    Dim sDate As Date, eDate As Date, sMonday As Date, eMonday As Date
    Dim iDay As Long, dAmt As Double, dUnit As Double
    ' *** for debugging
    sDate = #10/31/2024#
    eDate = #11/13/2024#
    dAmt = 48.25
'    sDate = #10/31/2024#
'    eDate = #11/13/2024#
'    dAmt = 47
    ' ***
    iDay = Application.NetworkDays(sDate, eDate)
    dUnit = dAmt / iDay
    sMonday = sDate + 1 - VBA.Weekday(sDate, vbMonday)
    eMonday = eDate + 1 - VBA.Weekday(eDate, vbMonday)
    Dim i As Date, WeekCnt As Long, iWorkDay As Long, iR As Long
    Dim WkEnd As Date, dAmtInWK As Double, dAmtInWK0 As Double, dSum As Double
    WeekCnt = (eMonday - sMonday) / 7 + 1
    Dim aRes(): ReDim aRes(1 To WeekCnt, 4)
    For i = sMonday To eMonday Step 7
        WkEnd = i + 6
        With Application
            iWorkDay = .NetworkDays(.Max(i, sDate), .Min(WkEnd, eDate))
            dAmtInWK0 = iWorkDay * dUnit
            dAmtInWK = .RoundDown(iWorkDay * dUnit * 4, 0) / 4
        End With
        dSum = dSum + dAmtInWK
        If i = eMonday Then
            dAmtInWK = dAmtInWK + (dAmt - dSum) / 2
            aRes(1, 1) = aRes(1, 1) + (dAmt - dSum) / 2
        End If
        iR = iR + 1
        aRes(iR, 0) = i
        aRes(iR, 1) = dAmtInWK
        aRes(iR, 2) = iWorkDay
        aRes(iR, 3) = dAmtInWK0
        aRes(iR, 4) = dSum
    Next
    For i = 1 To WeekCnt
        Debug.Print "[Week]:" & aRes(i, 0) & vbCr _
            ; "[Amt]:" & aRes(i, 1) & vbCr _
            ; "WorkingDay:" & aRes(i, 2) & vbCr _
            ; "Amt Before Round:" & aRes(i, 3) & vbCr _
            ; "Accumulated Amt:" & aRes(i, 4) & vbCr _
            ; " -------------------- "
    Next
End Sub

Output:
[Week]:2024/10/28
[Amt]:9.75
WorkingDay:2
Amt Before Round:9.65
Accumulated Amt:9.5
 -------------------- 
[Week]:2024/11/4
[Amt]:24  
WorkingDay:5
Amt Before Round:24.125 ' Do u think it should be rounded to 24 instead of 23.75
Accumulated Amt:33.5
 -------------------- 
[Week]:2024/11/11
[Amt]:14.5
WorkingDay:3
Amt Before Round:14.475
Accumulated Amt:47.75



Update:
Sub demo2()
    Dim sDate As Date, eDate As Date, sMonday As Date, eMonday As Date
    Dim iDay As Long, dAmt As Double, dUnit As Double
    ' *** for debugging
    sDate = #10/31/2024#
    eDate = #11/13/2024#
    dAmt = 48.25
'    sDate = #10/31/2024#
'    eDate = #11/13/2024#
'    dAmt = 47
    ' ***
    iDay = Application.NetworkDays(sDate, eDate)
    dUnit = Application.RoundDown(dAmt / iDay * 4, 0) / 4 '***
    sMonday = sDate + 1 - VBA.Weekday(sDate, vbMonday)
    eMonday = eDate + 1 - VBA.Weekday(eDate, vbMonday)
    Dim i As Date, j As Long, WeekCnt As Long, iWorkDay As Long, iR As Long
    Dim WkEnd As Date, dAmtInWK As Double, dAmtInWK0 As Double, dSum As Double
    WeekCnt = (eMonday - sMonday) / 7 + 1
    Dim aRes(): ReDim aRes(1 To WeekCnt, 4)
    Dim dTmp As Double
    For i = sMonday To eMonday Step 7
        WkEnd = i + 6
        With Application
            iWorkDay = .NetworkDays(.Max(i, sDate), .Min(WkEnd, eDate))
            dAmtInWK0 = iWorkDay * dUnit
            dAmtInWK = .RoundDown(iWorkDay * dUnit * 4, 0) / 4
            dSum = dSum + dAmtInWK
            iR = iR + 1
            aRes(iR, 0) = i
            aRes(iR, 1) = dAmtInWK
            aRes(iR, 2) = iWorkDay
            aRes(iR, 3) = dAmtInWK0
            aRes(iR, 4) = dSum
            If i = eMonday Then ' distribute remainder
                dTmp = (dAmt - dSum) / 0.25
                Dim sOffset As Long, eOffset As Long
                If dTmp Mod 2 = 0 Then
                    sOffset = dTmp / 2
                Else
                    sOffset = (dTmp / 2) - 0.5
                End If
                eOffset = dTmp - sOffset
                For j = 1 To WeekCnt
                    aRes(j, 1) = aRes(j, 1) + 0.25 * .Min(sOffset, aRes(j, 2))
                    sOffset = sOffset - aRes(j, 2)
                    If sOffset <= 0 Then Exit For
                Next
                For j = WeekCnt To 1 Step -1
                    aRes(j, 1) = aRes(j, 1) + 0.25 * .Min(eOffset, aRes(j, 2))
                    eOffset = eOffset - aRes(j, 2)
                    If eOffset <= 0 Then Exit For
                Next
                For j = 1 To WeekCnt ' for debugging
                    If j = 1 Then
                        dSum = aRes(j, 1)
                    Else
                        dSum = dSum + aRes(j, 1)
                    End If
                    aRes(j, 4) = dSum
                Next
            End If
        End With
    Next
    For j = 1 To WeekCnt
        Debug.Print "[Week]:" & aRes(j, 0) & vbCr _
            ; "[Amt]:" & aRes(j, 1) & vbCr _
            ; "WorkingDay:" & aRes(j, 2) & vbCr _
            ; "Amt Before Round:" & aRes(j, 3) & vbCr _
            ; "Accumulated Amt:" & aRes(j, 4) & vbCr _
            ; " -------------------- "
    Next
End Sub


Output:
[Week]:2024/10/28
[Amt]:9.75
WorkingDay:2
Amt Before Round:9.5
Accumulated Amt:9.75
 -------------------- 
[Week]:2024/11/4
[Amt]:23.75
WorkingDay:5
Amt Before Round:23.75
Accumulated Amt:33.5
 -------------------- 
[Week]:2024/11/11
[Amt]:14.75
WorkingDay:3
Amt Before Round:14.25
Accumulated Amt:48.25


You describe the gist of the issue, dividing a quantity across weeks with potentially unequal days across weeks and with each day receiving an amount of a specified increment.  In the example I used 0.25 as the increment.  That could be changed to 0.5.  Having said that, your output table is slightly off from the table 2 results.  ie 24 instead of 23.75

Verified Week 2, A, XXX =5 x 4.75 = 23.75

It's clear that 5 is working days in the 2nd week. May I know what's the logic of 4.75? Amt per day = 48.25 / 10 = 4.825.

for better or worse I tried to lay out the process vertically above the blue week.  Basically 48.25 need to be distributed over 10 weekdays.   48/10= 4.825.  Then round down to the nearest multiple of 0.25 = 4.75.  Then find the remainder after applying 4.75 for 10 days. so MOD(48.25,4.75) = 0.75.  Then determine how many days have that 0.25 added to them 0.75/.25 = 3.  Then split the extra days equally front and back and favour the backend when its an odd number of days so start = rounddown(3/2,0) and end= roundup(3/2,0).  Then each week needs to collect the hours for the dates with in them.

I see the difference now. I didn’t round down the daily amount (48.25) but instead rounded down the weekly amount (24.125, calculated as 4.825*5) to 24, resulting in a smaller remainder. If your business logic requires rounding at the daily level, you may skip my script.

I think I almost understand the distribution logic. Please check the updated script. It is validated with A-XXX and A-XYZ.

I can propose you the next solution:

Option Explicit

Sub Process()
  Dim lr&, fd&, ld&, i&, j&, r, d
  Dim pd#, strt#, endd#, totd#, da#, toth#
  Dim stadate#, enddate#, sd#, ed#
  Unpivot [D3]: [D1] = "Names": lr = [A1].CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
  stadate = Application.Min(Range("B2:B" & lr))
  enddate = Application.Max(Range("C2:C" & lr))
  sd = stadate - Weekday(stadate, vbMonday) + 1
  ed = enddate - Weekday(enddate, vbMonday) + 1
  fd = [F1].Column - 1: i = fd
  For pd = sd To ed Step 7
    i = i + 1: Cells(1, i) = pd
    Cells(1, i).NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd;@"
  Next
  ld = i - fd
  r = Range(Cells(1, fd + 1), Cells(1, i))
  ReDim d(1 To UBound(r, 2))
  For i = 2 To lr
    stadate = Cells(i, 2): enddate = Cells(i, 3)
    strt = stadate: totd = 0
    For j = 1 To ld ' calcs wdays per week, tot wdays
      If stadate < r(1, j) + 7 And enddate > r(1, j) Then
        endd = Application.Min(enddate, r(1, j) + 4)
        d(j) = endd - strt + 1: totd = totd + d(j): strt = r(1, j) + 7
      End If
    Next
    toth = Cells(i, 5): pd = Int(4 * toth / totd) / 4
    If pd > 0 Then
      lr = ((100 * toth) Mod (100 * pd)) / 25
    Else
      lr = toth / 0.25
    End If
    sd = lr \ 2: ed = (lr + 1) \ 2
    For j = 1 To ld ' calcs whrs per week
      If stadate < r(1, j) + 7 And enddate > r(1, j) Then
        lr = Application.Min(d(j), sd): da = d(j) * pd + lr * 0.25
        sd = sd - lr: totd = totd - d(j)
        If ed > totd Then
          da = da + (ed - totd) * 0.25: ed = totd
        End If
        toth = toth - da: Cells(i, j + fd) = da
      End If
    Next
  Next
  Range("B:C,E:E").Delete
End Sub

Sub Unpivot(pc As Range)
  Dim cws As Worksheet, vs As Long, cr As Long, cc As Long, i As Long, k As Long
  Dim dr As Long, dc As Long, da As Long, ca As Variant, cb As Variant
  Dim left As Long, right As Long, up As Long, down As Long
  cr = pc.Row: cc = pc.Column
  left = Cells(cr - 1, cc).End(xlToLeft).Column: up = Cells(cr, cc - 1).End(xlUp).Row
  right = cc: While Not IsEmpty(Cells(up, right + 1)): right = right + 1: Wend
  down = cr: While Not IsEmpty(Cells(down + 1, left)): down = down + 1: Wend
  Set cws = ActiveSheet: cws.Parent.Sheets.Add: i = 1
  cws.Range(cws.Cells(cr - 1, left), cws.Cells(cr - 1, cc - 1)).Copy
  [A1].PasteSpecial xlPasteValues: dr = cr - up: dc = cc - left + 1
  If dr > 1 Then
    cws.Range(cws.Cells(up, cc - 1), cws.Cells(cr - 2, cc - 1)).Copy
    Cells(1, dc).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
  End If
  da = dc + dr:   Cells(1, da - 1) = "TBD":   Cells(1, da) = "Value"
  k = 2: vs = right - cc + 1: dr = dr + 1
  cb = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(cws.Cells(up, cc).Resize(cr - up, right - cc + 1))
  For i = cr To down
    ca = cws.Range(cws.Cells(i, left), cws.Cells(i, cc - 1))
    Cells(k, 1).Resize(vs, dc - 1) = ca: Cells(k, dc).Resize(vs, dr) = cb
    cws.Cells(i, cc).Resize(1, vs).Copy
    Cells(k, da).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
    k = k + vs
  Next
End Sub



Verified Week 2, A, XXX =5 x 4.75 = 23.75.  Is your second week for a, xxx at 24 a rounding error / display setting?

for better or worse I tried to lay out the process vertically above the blue week.  Basically 48.25 need to be distributed over 10 weekdays.   48/10= 4.825.  Then round down to the nearest multiple of 0.25 = 4.75.  Then find the remainder after applying 4.75 for 10 days. so MOD(48.25,4.75) = 0.75.  Then determine how many days have that 0.25 added to them 0.75/.25 = 3.  Then split the extra days equally front and back and favour the backend when its an odd number of days so start = rounddown(3/2,0) and end= roundup(3/2,0).  Then each week needs to collect the hours for the dates with in them.

because the smallest increment is 0.25.  So the 0.75 gets split out in 3 increments of 0.25.  1 on the first day, one on the last day, and since there is one extra is goes to the 2nd last days.  had there been a 4th it would have gone to the second day, and had there been a 5th it would have gone to the 3rd last day.  Basically its keeping each day as low as possible then adding the little bit of extra on the ends working towards the middle while favouring the end when its not an even split.
